# IE 11 keep crashing and hanging

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

For some reason IE around the company is keep hanging when opening new page or opening new tabs.

It only happens to some user not all users.

We are using Window 7 Enterprise.

This been happening from last 3 weeks. They was update that time which I have removed from one of the PC but still they is no different

These are things I have tried.

- Remove IE11 and install IE8 (it got very bad)
- Install all updates for IE and Windows
- Run Fixit
- Run IE without any add-ons
- Reset IE

Comment: Don't use IE. Use a normal web browser.

Comment: Cant use any other browser as nothing works with other browser (Company things, sharepoint ext...). Only IE. I have tried other browser which do work perfectly fine.

Comment: does it crashes while u browsing url or once clicked on new tab friend?if its crashing it might be flash plugin or activex issue http://www.thewindowsclub.com/internet-explorer-freezes-crashes-hangs

Comment: corporate questions are off-topic here

Comment: capture a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/SxrK4LWY and share the compressed file.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you should disable IE and use another browser, I.E Chrome (google.com/Chrome). You can do so like this:

> Start > Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features On/Off > Untick Internet Explorer

Remember, you will then need to remove **all** shortcuts to IE and set your new browser as  default. To download Chrome for example:

> www.google.com/Chrome then click Download Chrome
>   Then wait for download to complete.
>
> Open the downloaded file and wait for the installer to install Chrome

Volia!

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP has specifically stated that [using other browsers is not an option](http://superuser.com/questions/938338/ie-11-keep-crashing-and-hanging/939248#comment1275245_938338).

Comment: Well can I just point out that it was not obvious sorry.

Comment: I agree that perhaps it should have been stated in the question itself, but on Super User (and Stack Exchange in general), we strive to answer *the question as asked*. The question (despite its problems) is about MSIE, not web browsers in general, and thus answers should focus on MSIE.

Comment: Ok but since it wasn't obvious could you please help me learn by upvoting again thank you